Attempting to coerce observations in a new predictor to perform logistic function in Medicaid spending dataset
I am analyzing data on the Medicaid Spending by Drug Data Dictionary  dataset. Specifically, I want to perform a logistic regression, where y should be the CAGR_Avg_Spnd_Per_Dsg_Unt_18_22.
Unfortunately, the class and mode remain as characters based on my code.
My inspiration for the "Up" and "Down" approach comes from the following:
# The library comes from Introduction to Statistical Learning: With Applications in R

library(ISLR)
attach(Smarket)
summary(Smarket)
# desired output:
glm.fit=glm(Direction~Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume,
            family=binomial,data=Smarket)
contrasts(Direction)

By using glm.fit, I can perform predictions, create a confusion matrix, and more.
However, when examining
summary(drug.spending)

My "Up" and "Down" are characters, while the authors to ISLR's "Up" and "Down" appear to be numerically counted. The authors never offered a code for doing that with their data frame's "Up" and "Down" observations!
Here is my code:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(psych)
library(leaps)
set.seed(1)

spending <- read.csv("medicaid_spending_by_drug_data_dictionary.csv")
drug.spending <-  spending %>%
  na.omit(spending) %>%
  filter(Mftr_Name == "Overall") %>%
  arrange(desc(Tot_Mftr)) %>%
  filter(duplicated(Gnrc_Name))
drug.spending <- drug.spending[!duplicated(drug.spending$Gnrc_Name),]
attach(drug.spending)



drug.spending <- drug.spending %>%
  mutate(CAGR_Direction = ifelse(CAGR_Avg_Spnd_Per_Dsg_Unt_18_22 > 0, 'Up', 'Down'))
drug.spending$CAGR_Direction <- factor(drug.spending$CAGR_Direction, levels = c('Down', 'Up')) # Update #1

summary(drug.spending)
contrasts(CAGR_Direction) #gives an error

I have used different coercions, such as as.numeric() and as.integer(). I am not exactly sure where I am going wrong...

drug.spending <- drug.spending %>%
  mutate(CAGR_Direction = ifelse(CAGR_Avg_Spnd_Per_Dsg_Unt_18_22 > 0, 'Up', 'Down'))
drug.spending$CAGR_Direction <- factor(drug.spending$CAGR_Direction, levels = c('Down', 'Up'))

Factor the CAGR directions

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
